# move a ball on arrow key press in javascript

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, html5-canvas

i am trying javascript for the first time... i want to make a ball move on pressing the arrow keys

but the ball the is not moving up and down... it is only moving left and right...

i have some queries

1. how to make the ball move diagonally when up and right keys are
   pressed
2. i tried using acceleration but how to make the ball
   smoothly stop when no keys are getting pressed
3. how to make the
   ball freely roam around in the canvas (by making key presses)...
   right now it is just moving in one direction. but i want to make the
   ball move freely according to key presses.

```
  canwid=1000;
canhigh=600;
sidexl=0;
hxl=0;
canvas = document.getElementById("game");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

gameover=false;
x=canwid/2;
y=canhigh/2;

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

    function keyDownHandler(e) {
        if(e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
            rightPressed = true;
            if (sidexl<2) {
                sidexl+=0.02;
            }
        }
        else if(e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
            leftPressed = true;
            if (sidexl>-2) {
                sidexl-=0.02;
            }
        }
        else if(e.key == "Up" || e.key == "ArrowUp") {
            upPressed = true;
            if (hxl>-2) {
                hxl+=0.02;
            }
        }
        else if(e.key == "Down" || e.key == "ArrowDown") {
            downPressed = true;
            if (hxl>-2) {
                hxl-=0.02;
            }
        }
    }
    function keyUpHandler(e) {
    if(e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
        rightPressed = false;
    }
    else if(e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
        leftPressed = false;
    }    
    else if(e.key == "Up" || e.key == "ArrowUp") {
        upPressed = false;
    }    
    else if(e.key == "Down" || e.key == "ArrowDown") {
        downPressed = false;
    }
}

function draw()
{
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}
function input()
{

}
function logic()
{
    if (rightPressed) {
        x += sidexl;    
    }
    else if (leftPressed) 
    {
        x += sidexl;    
    }   
    else if (upPressed) 
    {
        y += hxl;   
    }   
    else if (downPressed) 
    {
        y += hxl;   
    }
    else
    {
        x += sidexl;
        y += hxl;
        if (sidexl>0) {
            sidexl-=0.02;
        }
        else {
            sidexl+=0.02;
        }
        if (hxl>0) {
            hxl-=0.02;
        }
        else {
            hxl+=0.02;
        }
    }
}
function play()
{
    draw();
    input();
    logic();
}

setInterval(play, 5);
```

Comment: Can you please add the Java code to the question so we can see how it's relevant?

Comment: @Snow sorry i accidently added that tag... i removed it ... please remove your downvote... i am stuck on this since morning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to make the ball move diagonally when up and right keys are
>   pressed i tried using acceleration but how to make the ball smoothly
>   stop when no keys are getting pressed how to make the ball freely roam
>   around in the canvas (by making key presses)... right now it is just
>   moving in one direction. but i want to make the ball move freely
>   according to key presses.

You can achieve that by storing acceleration for x,y and keys pressed state

Here's the working example

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("game");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth / 2;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight / 2;

let gameover = false;
let x = canvas.width / 2;
let y = canvas.height / 2;
let dx = 0;
let dy = 0;

const state = {
  "ArrowRight": false,
  "ArrowLeft": false,
  "ArrowUp": false,
  "ArrowDown": false
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function determineDirection() {
  const {
    ArrowRight,
    ArrowLeft,
    ArrowUp,
    ArrowDown
  } = state
  if (ArrowRight && ArrowUp) {
    return {
      dx: .25,
      dy: -.25
    };
  }
  if (ArrowRight && ArrowDown) {
    return {
      dx: .25,
      dy: .25
    };
  }
  if (ArrowLeft && ArrowUp) {
    return {
      dx: -.25,
      dy: -.25
    };
  }
  if (ArrowLeft && ArrowDown) {
    return {
      dx: -.25,
      dy: .25
    };
  }
  if (ArrowLeft) {
    return {
      dx: -.25,
      dy: 0
    }
  }
  if (ArrowRight) {
    return {
      dx: .25,
      dy: 0
    }
  }
  if (ArrowUp) {
    return {
      dx: 0,
      dy: -.25
    }
  }
  if (ArrowDown) {
    return {
      dx: 0,
      dy: .25
    }
  }
  return {
    dx: 0,
    dy: 0
  }
}

function keyDownHandler({
  key
}) {
  state[key] = true;
}

function keyUpHandler({
  key
}) {
  state[key] = false;
}

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  context.fillStyle = "red";
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();
}

function logic() {
  const direction = determineDirection();

  if (direction.dx) {
    dx = dx + direction.dx
  }

  if (direction.dy) {
    dy = dy + direction.dy
  }

  x = x + dx;
  y = y + dy;
;
  if (dx > 0) {
    dx -= 0.02;
  }
  if (dx < 0) {
    dx += 0.02;
  }
  if (dy > 0) {
    dy -= 0.02;
  }
  if (dy < 0) {
    dy += 0.02;
  }

}

function play() {
  draw();
  logic();
}

setInterval(play, 50);
```

```html
<canvas id="game"></canvas>
```

Comment: you made exactly what i needed